# How do I password-protect access to specific apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, security, iphone

currently, I have a 4 digit lock on my phone.

I know this isn't really secure - and can be broken through if neccessary. It just kind of stops the situation if someone picks up my phone, they won't be able to dial people or write and read my emails straight away.

What I find is that most of the apps I have aren't really worth securing. Like I don't care if someone plays a game or plays a song or checks the weather. And it's really annoying having to unlock the phone every time I want to do anything with it.

Essentially, it's just the stuff like phone, messages, email that I would like a code for.

So I was wondering, are there any features on the phone or any apps that'll allow me to only ask for a keycode when I want to open certain icons or apps?

Answer (score 8):

The only way to passcode protect individual applications, including built in system ones is to jailbreak the phone and install a jailbreak tweak like [Locktopus](http://www.howtogeek.com/93688/locktopus-locks-down-individual-apps-on-ios-devices/) or [Lockdown Pro](http://thebigboss.org/lockdown-pro-password-protect-your-applications-now-released). Both of these tweaks let you set a text passcode as well as a numerical one. The reason an AppStore application cannot provide this functionality is because AppStore apps are Sandboxed. This means they are limited in how they can interact with other applications, and the iPhone itself.

Alternatively, replace the application you are currently using with an AppStore alternative that has a passcode lock built into the application. This wont protect the data in the original app, but if you want to secure data behind a passcode you could move the data into the passcode protected application and delete it from the original application. This obviously wont work for contacts, but could work for photos and notes.

See the iOS application "[MyPics](http://www.uvento.com/mypics)" for an example of a photo app where you can set a passcode to protect access. Another example is the [My Secret Folder](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-secret-folder/id456939837?mt=8) application which lets you import data into it and set a passcode to prevent people from accessing that data within the app.

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for a while too. "My Secret Folder" along with every other security app I've seen on the App Store will only secure contacts, notes, pictures, and videos. And that's only if you import them into that program. It DOES NOT allow you to put an app in the secured folder. You can not lock an "APP" without a jailbreak.

When the app comes available to password protect an "APP", or even a real folder, I will buy it. (I think Apple should include the option in the next update)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [My secret folder app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-secret-folder/id456939837?mt=8) which requires a password to access it. Then your apps would be in there.

Comment: Can you please add a link?

Comment: this is spam - you can not secure your iphone with third perty apps ! you only can make encnypted files ìnside a app - not other apps.

Comment: I wouldn't call this spam since Graeme isn't only pimping this app. I would however downvote it since it's been removed from sale in the US app store and perhaps worldwide for likely violation of Apple's rules for an app store app calling private API. We don't remove wrong answers and expect people to edit them (if possible) and downvote them if they can't be improved without changing the entire meaning of the answer.

Comment: @Pfitz - You are totally correct that there isn't a jailbreak free manner of securing arbitrary apps on iOS due to sandboxing and code signing implementation by Apple.

Comment: @Pfitz not spam, I have no connection to teh developers of this app

Answer (score -2):

Doc Vault is a pretty handy app to protect privacy and keep files locked while the iPhone can still be used as usual.
It creates a separate area that can only be accessed with a separate pass key. Included is a little browser that allows to hide the history and a tool to create pdf from text.
Check it out here:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doc-vault-individual-access/id551638522?l=de&ls=1&mt=8

Comment: it maybe creates a secure way to store files FROM THIS App encrypted but you can not secure files from other apps or other apps itself!